# primefaces datatable select all with paginator

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I have a p:datatable with multiple selection mode and a paginator.

```
<p:datatable value=#{rows} selection=#{selectedRows} pagintor="true" rows="20" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" paginatorPosition="bottom">
  <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
  <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"/>
  ... columns ...
</p:datatable>
```

When i click the header checkbox all rows are selected. When i click on the header checkbox to select all rows and then want to export the selected rows (by using the values of 'selection'), it only returns 20 objects. I expect that when i use the header checkbox it selects all rows of the datatable, and not only the one of the page. I have a datatable with more then 200 pages, so you can imagine it is a very tedious job to export all of the when using a paginator ;).

I suppose it is a bug I should log, or am I missing something? I looked through the documentation but it says nothing about using multiple selection mode together with pagination... Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select all in datatable jsf primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965320/select-all-in-datatable-jsf-primefaces)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same requirement - `select all rows across pages`.

What I did - provided an `<p:inputSwitch />` to toggle all rows across all the pages.

Copied and is as below -

```
<p:dataTable id="id" var="var" widgetVar="wvar" rowsPerPageTemplate="7,15" reflow="true"
    value="#{backingBean.dataModel}" paginator="true" rows="7" rowIndexVar="index" rowKey="#{var.id}"
    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    selection="#{backingBean.selectedItems}">
<c:facet name="header"...
<p:inputSwitch value="#{backingBean.allRecords}" onLabel="All" offLabel="None" >
    <p:ajax onstart="if (PF('wvar').getSelectedRowsCount() == 0) PF('wvar').selectAllRows(); else PF('wvar').unselectAllRows();" />
</p:inputSwitch>

private boolean allRecords;//Getter++Setter++
```

And, defined `toggleSelect` event as below -

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" onstart="if (PF('wvar').getSelectedRowsCount() == 7 || PF('wvar').getSelectedRowsCount() == 15) PF('wvar').selectAllRows(); else PF('wvar').unselectAllRows();" />
```

where `7` and `15` comes from the datatable `rowsPerPageTemplate="7,15"`.

Works for me.(PrimeFaces 5.3)

Answer (score 0):

FOR JSF 2 ,for selected all rows on datatable in selectionMode multiple with `paginator=true`: 
In Page

```html
<p:dataTable widgetVar="tableArea" yourtags...>
     <p:ajax  event="toggleSelect" oncomplete="teste()" /> /// toggleSelect is dispared on click to checkbox header
     <p:column id="columnId" selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

In js:

```js
function teste(){
  
 var checked = $(document).find(":checkbox")["0"].checked; ///Find checkbox header and verify if checkbox is checked
 if(checked == true){
  PF('tableArea').selectAllRows(); // if true, selectAllRows from datatable
 } else {
  PF('tableArea').unselectAllRows(); //
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample Code:-

**JAVA (your backing bean class)
==============================**
//Stores the checked items from data table.
private List<String> selectedIds = new ArrayList<>();

private List<String> getSomeList() {
// return list of strings to data table
  return someList;
}

public void selectAllCheckboxes(ToggleSelectEvent event) {
if (selectedIds != null)  {
    selectedIds.clear();
    if (event.isSelected()) {
        selectedIds.addAll(someList); //Add all the elements from getSomeList()
    }
 }
}

**XHTML
=====**

<p:dataTable id="data-table-id" value="#{backingBean.someList}"
selection="#{backingBean.selectedIds}" rowKey="#{id}" var="id"                   
paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom"
paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" rowSelectMode="checkbox"
rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,50">

<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" 
update="@this"listener="#backingBean.selectAllCheckboxes}"/>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: selection="selectedIds" saves a list of checkbox items.To select all the items in the datatable add entire list to "selectedIds" and all the items will be checked by default.

Answer (score -1):

> I expect that when i use the header checkbox it selects all rows of the datatable, and not only the one of the page.

This is a wrong expectation.

> I suppose it is a bug I should log,

Nope.

> or am I missing something?

No, it is by design. So other than having the wrong expectation you did not miss anything. The fact that you are the first one in SO to ask this and the second one if you count the number of requests in the PrimeFaces forum to is an indication of this.

Not even GMail does this btw. They give you the option to select all message on the page you are on, and when you do this they give you an **additional** option to select **all messages across all pages**

Comment: Those are not valid arguments. It seems more it is not taken into account, and therefore accepted as a design choice.

Maybe no-one bothered to ask this question? Maybe some people are lazy and go to select every page iso wondering why there couldn't be a select all pages checkbox? 

Also, and most importantly, if no-one cared at Gmail, why DID they add the functionality to select all pages? ;) Apparently Gmail users also had this expectation...

Anyway if i consider to log this, it will be as an enhancement (not a bug i mean), but first need an elegant way. 

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Question has been asked before... 1 time... you are the second. Maybe a 'select all' is not needed as much as you think, or others have a simple solution...